# Percent Rating Bar in Swift

Tags: swift, rating

I have data on `votes/total votes` and I would like to add a percent rating bar that shows the percentage of votes. ie: 95% and fills the bar 95%. I couldn't find any swift instruction on this (except to give UISlider a try).

Example:

```
Rating Bar (350/700 votes):
[==========50%            ]

Rating Bar (180/200 votes):
[==========90%==========  ]

Rating Bar (213/709 votes):
[======    30%            ]
```

Comment: Why not show a `UILabel` on top of a `UIProgressView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UIView` as background view. Then, add another view as subview as the progress bar. Let`s implement that as a class:

```
class ProgressView: UIView {

    var progress: CGFloat = 0
    var filledView: UIView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        filledView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: frame.height))
        filledView.backgroundColor = Colors.fontColor

        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(filledView)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // <-- You need to implement this
        fatalError()
    }

    func setProgess(var progress: CGFloat) {
        progress = min(max(progress, 0), 1) // Between 0 and 1
        self.progress = progress

        filledView.frame.size.width = self.frame.width * progress
    }
}
```

Now you can also add a `UILabel` to show the percentage if you want to.

Comment: I keep getting fatal error at `self.filledView = PageItemController().rating1` http://i.imgur.com/t4wBkwg.png ... on my `PageItemController` I have set `self.rating1.frame = CGRectMake(100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0)`

Comment: Hmm. Why don't you copy the standard init stuff into `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`?

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to programming. What did you mean by standard init stuff? I thought I had to initialize `self.filledView` with the `UIView` I created on the storyboard

Comment: No, filledView is the progress bar, this should be done like in `init(frame : CGRect)`. Better initialize `self` from the storyboard, not `self.filledView`.

Comment: Ok, i think I get what you mean. But when I use the standard init, it get an error for using the property frame before it is initialized http://i.imgur.com/gIcbzxo.png

Comment: Okay, then do the super.init(...) part at the top of the method; also change `var filledView: UIView` to `var filledView: UIView!` (note the exclamation mark).

Comment: That allows me to compile but the view doesn't show anything. Sorry if this seems obvious :( On my viewcontroller I used the following code: `self.rating1.frame = CGRectMake(100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0); self.rating1.progress = 0.50`

Comment: You should use the method `self.rating1.setProgress(0.5)`. This updates the `filledView`.

Comment: And of course you should, if you didn't, give the `filledView` an appropriate color in `init`.

Comment: thanks for your help on this. the `filledView` is set to `UIColor.blackColor()`. I used `setProgress(0.5)`, but it is still not showing anything. Is the rating1.frame correct? `self.rating1.frame = CGRectMake(100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0)`

Comment: yes, that is correct. don't know where the error is. maybe self.rating1 is not added as a subview?

Comment: wow, yes that was the issue. thank you so much for your tremendous help. I just have one last question, how can I make `self.rating1.frame = CGRectMake()` the size of my storyboard UIView (instead of setting it manually?)

Comment: Glad I could help :) hm, maybe you connect an UIView IBOutlet, and instead of using this outlet, you create a ProgressView with the frame of this outlet.